# Confusion regarding the relationship of marginal and joint distributions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(X,Y)$ be a two-dimensional random variable with a joint density $f_{(X,Y)}$ of $\mathbb{P}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let me first write down a few common definitions to state my question properly. But be aware that I have some sort of confusion, so some of the following definitions might already be faulty:

A measurable map $f:\Omega \to [0,\infty)$ is called *density* of $\mathbb{P}$ with respect to a second measure $\mu$, if
$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \int_{A}f{\rm d}\mu \quad \text{for all } A\in \Sigma.$$
In the setting of this question $\mu = \lambda^2$, the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The usual definition of the *marginal density of $X$* in this context is
$$f_{X}(x_0) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x_0,y)dy.$$
As $f_X$ is a density we have $\mathbb{P}(X \in B) = \mathbb{P}_{X}(B \in \Sigma) = \int_B f_{X}(x)dx$ for $B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

As $f_{(X,Y)}$ is a joint density for $(X,Y)$ we also have for all Borel sets $A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$
$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in A) = \int_{A} f_{(X,Y)}(x,y){\rm d}\lambda^2(x,y)$$
As far as I know the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is generated by sets of the form $(a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2]$, where $a_1 \leq b_1, a_2 \leq b_2$. So by Fubini's theorem we can also write the equation as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in A) &= \int_{A_1} \int_{A_2} f_{(X,Y)}(x,y){\rm d}y{\rm d}x \quad \text{with } A = A_1 \times A_2\\
&= \int_{A_1} f_{X}(x) {\rm d}x\\
&= \mathbb{P}_{X}(A_1).
\end{align*}
Which is to say the joint *distribution* equals the marginal distribution of $X$, which is certainly false. However, at which point does the argument fail exactly? Why cannot we not recover the joint distribution via the marginal distribution? If I recall correctly, this is only possible if $X,Y$ are independent, but I cannot connect the dots and I'd like to understand the exact problem with my argument to get a better understanding of what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: How do you justify the second equality? It seems to fail in general unless $A_2=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right. I guess to get $f_X$  in this step it's really necessary to integrate over the whole range of possible values for $y$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$. Then $P((X,Y) \in A\times\mathbb{R}) = P_{X}(A)$ for $A$ a one-dim. Borelset which also makes sense i guess ...